# visual studio 2012 ,tfs project loading failed

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My admin of the TFS rename the project name and when i get the latest version all other projects are loaded to my local visual studio but the project which have been renamed is not loading . I tried to delete the solution from the local mapped path and then got again latest version but still the problem is same and its give me a message that the Project file .csproj  has been moved ,rename or not in you computer. I also tried to delete the .SUO file and get specific and latest version restart visual studio added the existing project to solution . I spent many days to resolve the issue but I am not able to do so , can any one help me in this Problem ,

Comment: Have you tried right-clicking and removing the broken project link and then right-clicking on the solution and adding an existing project? You could then browse to the newly renamed project. Maybe I'm missing something here?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud : sorry but there is no option for Removing the Broken project or same like this.

Answer (score 0):

Check the solution file when it comes our of TFS. I have had an issue similar to this, and I could see the correct files comin out of TFS into my local workspace, but the minute I loaded it it VS, all of the old code came back.
Eventually I discovered the solution file still referenced my old code, which caused it to be loaded in from the TFS profile.
See if the admin physically renamed the files in TFS but didnt change the details in the soluton and project files.

Comment: I did found the .sln and .suo files which is hidden by default , and deleted it from my local machine and then got latest version . all other project are ok except the project which have been renamed by the admin.and cannot be loaded

Comment: Did you open the .sln file in notepad or something similar, and check that the newly renamed project is listed?

Comment: Yeah i have open the .sln file in node pad .but magically all the other Project name with .csproj extension exist except the one which is rename and is not visible in node pad . can you help out me in this issu .

Comment: So are you missing the .csproj file, or is the .sln file missing a link to the project file?